# How to get the entire elements in x after the for loop for plotting in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, sapply

I was wondering how I could get the entire **5** elements of the vector `x` *after the `for-loop`* much like I get the **5** elements of the vector `ts` in my R code below:

```
if(!require(BayesFactor)){install.packages('BayesFactor')} ; library(BayesFactor)

ts = numeric(5)
x = numeric(5)

for(i in 1:5){

 x = c(1, 3, 10, 30, 100)[i]

 f <- function(t){
 abs(ttest.tstat( t, 50, 50, rscale = sqrt(2)/2, simple = TRUE)[[1]] - x)
 }

 ts[i] = optimize(f, interval = c(-6, 6))[[1]]
  }

plot(ts, x, t = "o") #`x` contains only the last element (i.e., 100) of the `x` vector above
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initiate the `x` vector before the loop, then refer to it in the loop. That way you'll still have it afterwards.

```
x = c(1, 3, 10, 30, 100)

for(i in 1:5){

    x_int = x[i]

    f <- function(t){
        abs(ttest.tstat( t, 50, 50, rscale = sqrt(2)/2, simple = TRUE)[[1]] - x_int)
    }

    ts[i] = optimize(f, interval = c(-6, 6))[[1]]
}

plot(ts, x, t = "o")
```

Here's an equivalent operation using `sapply` (I haven't tested this, please test for yourself, and let me know if it doesn't work as expected):

```
x = c(1, 3, 10, 30, 100)

f <- function(t, x_int){
    abs(ttest.tstat( t, 50, 50, rscale = sqrt(2)/2, simple = TRUE)[[1]] - x_int)
}

ts <- sapply( x, function(i) optimize(f, interval = c(-6, 6), x_int = i)[[1]] )

plot(ts, x, t = "o")
```

Comment: You could certainly use `sapply`, yes. The main thing is to have your `x` vector created, then refer to it, rather than creating the vector on each iteration of the loop. That way, you've got the entire vector ready when you want it, be that inside or outside the loop. This applies to `for` and `sapply` equally.

Comment: I've added an `sapply` solution, but I don't have `BayesFactor` installed, so please test for yourself.

Comment: Great! FYI, I've done some benchmarking on `for` vs `sapply` here, and the speeds come out almost identical. So speed should not be a deciding factor between the two solutions.

Comment: Great to know, but `Vectorize()` is not applicable here right? (it's just I'm sure very fast)

Comment: You can use `Vectorize()`, but you won't see any speed increase in doing so, so I wouldn't see any reason to here.

Comment: Do you mind writing the above using `Vectorize()` I just got curious to see this?